# How to setup routing in Linux to create a NVA in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, networking, routes

I am trying to deploy a hub & spoke topology on Azure. I have VNet: hub, spoke1 & spoke2, respectively with the 3 following address spaces: `10.0.0.0/16`, `10.1.0.0/16` & `10.2.0.0/16`. And each have only one subnet on the `/24` address space.

I have peered each spoke to the hub and deployed a Linux machine in my hub subnet. Now, I want to use that Linux machine as a router to forward traffic coming from `10.1.0.0/16` and targetting `10.2.0.0/16` to the spoke2 VNet and vice-versa.

I have added a `User Defined Route` on each spoke to use the Linux router IP address (`10.0.0.5`) as the Next hop when targetting the other spoke.

I have enable `ip_forwarding` on my Linux machine: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and added 2 routes `ip route add 10.1.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0` and `ip route add 10.2.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0` since `10.0.0.1` is my gateway on my router and `eth0` my NIC.
I have also enabled `IP Forwarding` on the NIC of my router in Azure.

But... this does not work. Packets are not forwarded to appropriate network and I don't understand why.

If any of you has a hint or even the solution to implement this I would appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

I don't know exactly what went wrong during my first tries.

I simply dropped the Resource Group and restarted from scratch with Windows VM, following [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal).

Then, I replaced step by step the Windows VM by Linux VM... and everything is working.
On the NVA, you simply have to:

1. enable the `IP Forwarding` **on** the Network Interface of the VM in Azure,
2. enable the `IP Forwarding` **in** the VM:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=/net.ipv4.ip_forward=/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sed -i 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward=0/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sed -i 's/#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=/net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sed -i 's/net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0/net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

Then define routes in Azure (`Route table` + `Routes`) in each spoke to forward traffic to the NVA IP.

Nothing more. Works out of the box.

I even created my NVA in a `Virtual Machine Scale Set` behind an Internal `Load Balancer` with `HA-Ports`, so my NVA is highly available.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about the setup for NIC for specific machine:

[image]

BTW: Microsoft has an [easy tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal) on this.

Comment: Hi @maras2002, I have already enabled IP Forwarding on my NIC. Thanks.

BTW, the tutorial you are pointing to "assumes you're using Windows Server 2019 Datacenter". My problem here is regarding Linux configuration.

Comment: It is really sad you minused this answer. Why: a) you did not state in your initial post taht your have this option on NIC marked (you added in after Edit). b) article clearly states: "This tutorial assumes you're using Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. **You can select a different operating system if you want.**"

Comment: 1) That's not me who downvoted. 2) I agree. The article states that I can use a different OS. And I clearly stated that my problem is with a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud configure the linux machine as a router.

1. create a linux bridge, and attach the `eth0`.
2. set the bridge ip as `10.0.0.1/24`, and setup a dhcp server on it.
3. on each spokes, set `10.0.0.1` as next hop for target network.
4. On the linux machine, add router entry to `10.1.0.0/24` and `10.2.0.0/24` through `10.0.0.1`.